# Presigned URL dont work for PUT but it works for GET S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having a trouble with Amazon S3 presigned URL. In my configuration of bucket policy I give access only to an specific IAM User, I mean, is not public. So, If I navigate in the browser to a file url of my S3 bucket, I receive an access denied message.
So, I use the aws-cli tool to generate a presigned url of that file. With that URL I'm able to get the file correctly, but the issue is when I try to put a file to the bucket. Using that url I cannot put a file beacuse I'm getting this message error:

`<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

What I'm missing?

Comment: I believe the HTTP verb (e.g. `GET` or `POST`) is encoded into the presigned URL, so if you use the presigned URL you made for `GET` in a `POST` request, you'll get this sot of error. I'm not sure whether it's possible to make a single presigned URL that can be used for both.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a different presigned URL for `PUT` methods and `GET` methods. This is because the HTTP verb (`PUT`, `GET`, etc.) is part of the "CanonicalResource" used to construct the signature. See ["Authenticating Requests" in the Amazon S3 reference docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) for details.

Comment: Consider s/POST/PUT/g.  `POST` uploads require a signed policy document, but `PUT` uploads can use a signed URL.

Comment: Edited. (The original question was about `PUT` anyway.)